# Need current Location cordinates

Tags: android, gps, location

package com.demo.location;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyLocation  extends Activity
{
    LocationManager mlocManager;
    LocationListener mlocListener;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        /* Use the LocationManager class to obtain GPS locations */
        mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
    }

    /* Class My Location Listener */
    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
    {

        //@Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
        {
            Log.e("","HERE It IS");
            loc.getLatitude();
            loc.getLongitude();

            Log.e("","LAT"+loc.getLatitude());
            Log.e("","LONG"+loc.getLongitude());
            String Text = "My current location is: " +
            "Latitud = " + loc.getLatitude() +
            "Longitud = " + loc.getLongitude();

            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), Text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        //@Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
        {
            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Gps Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        }

        //@Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
        {
            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Gps Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        //@Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
        {

        }
    }
}



Manifest File

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

I just need the exact location where the user is.Upon running this application I am getting nothing from the emulator and device...(Samsung Galaxy GT S5360). Also I just need lat & long & need to pass that as parameter into other method, so any other solution is also appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: *I am not getting anything from the emulator*: Are you sure your emulator emulates a GPS device? *...and device*: Do you have clear unobstructed view of the sky?

Comment: @npinti The weather here is cloudy at the moment...

Comment: Clouds should not block the signal. Maybe doing what V.J. suggests will do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
locManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
```

isteadof

```
locManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
```

it is helpful for me in my case.

Please also add the following permission.

```
android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION
```

Comment: If you are working on simulator the LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER provide you the current lat lon.
or you are testing it on device then use  LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER.

Comment: its giving me exact result on s5360 is giving me details but when deployed on s5830 its giving me an toast saying GPS disabled..

Comment: Please add the following permissions in menifest.

ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION

and try..

Comment: added those permissions in manifest but still the same issue :(

Comment: The NETWORK_PROVIDER will only work when your device have an network connection Like. Mobile Provider, WiFi, GPRS etc.

So Please check the network connection in your s5830. and then try..

Comment: Please insert INTERNET permission.